# MPU 6050 DMP Output Values Units Issue

Tags: accelerometer, gyroscope, mpu

I'm running into an odd issue with a motion control processor (MPU 6050 / 9150) that is returning raw gyroscope values as specified between the -/+ 32768 which in the way this gyro is configured corresponds to -/+ 2000 deg / sec. This makes total sense as this goes along with the specified documentation.

However, when i process data from the digital motion processor (6 axis sensor fusion) i get a maximum of 1429. I don't think that there's an error reading the data from the mpu buffer as the other measurements look good (reading from the same FIFO buffer). I assume this is likely some units issue that has to do with the 6 axis sensor fusion, and also likely involving radians

Wondering if any of you bright people with your light bulb brains have some insight here?

Thanks!